# Error: <tspan> attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN". | Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0". | Raphael.js | wheelnav.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, raphael, wheelnav.js

I am trying to create circular menu with wheelnav.js library.
 
Even though it seems to work I get thousands of errors in chrome console.

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0". 
Error:  attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN".

[image: errors from chrome console, raphaeljs]

During my own debugging I managed to find the same causes that people list in these threads:

https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/593 
 https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/620 
https://github.com/fperucic/treant-js/issues/73

Even though these threads are quite old, they are still opened and I couldn't find there soulution to my problem. I couldn't even find an elegant method to overwrite raphaels' functions.

```
 var icons = {
    'section_sign': '\u00A7\n',
    'key': '\uf084\n',
    'cogs': '\uf085\n',
 };

var items = [ {title: icons.key + 'Security&\nPasswords'},
              {title: icons.cogs + 'Settings&\nDevice'},
              {title: icons.section_sign + 'Rules&\nLaw'} ];

var piemenu = new wheelnav('main_menu');
piemenu.initWheel(items.map(function(item){
                                        return item.title;
                                    }));
piemenu.createWheel();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swiatek7/t08udf7m/22/)

Any ideas?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

wheelnav.js uses a modified Raphael.js

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wheelnav@1.7.1/js/dist/raphael.min.js
```

Here is an error-free JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npg80xqm

You can find the fixed bugs here: https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/commits/master/js/required/raphael.js

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves: Error: attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0"., but Error: <tspan> attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN" still happens.

Comment: Do you see this error in modified JSFiddle? I don't.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of solution was already in the issue https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/593 . So I found the following bodge by adding:

```
if(isNaN(fontSize)) {
    fontSize = 10;
}
```

to raphael.js after:

```
fontSize = node.firstChild ? toInt(R._g.doc.defaultView.getComputedStyle(node.firstChild, E).getPropertyValue("font-size"), 10) : 10;
```

(line 6147 in 2.3.0) solved the `<tspan>` errors for me.