# Error: <tspan> attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN" - Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, raphael, nan

I've got a lot of errors when hiding/showing object made in raphael.
I have a house made with raphael - when button clicked a gauge is shown and animating, if you click again the house is showing and animating again (function running over and over again when clicking)

This function is showing on phone, on normal desktop the function isn't used. So therefor I can't just put the function on the button.

BUT! I got a lot of errors when doing it.
Made a fiddle showing it. [See it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5mv0enuz/2/)

[image: Error]

Full js code here:

```
pv = 80;        
pointerv = Math.round(pv);


onload = function() {

$(function dogauge() {
  var Needle, arc, arcEndRad, arcStartRad, barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, el, endPadRad, height, i, margin, needle, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, percent, radius, ref, sectionIndx, sectionPerc, startPadRad, svg, totalPercent, width;

  percent = pointerv/100;

  barWidth = 40;

  numSections = 3;

  // / 2 for HALF circle
  sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;

  padRad = 0.05;

  chartInset = 10;

  // start at 270deg
  totalPercent = .75;

  el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  };

  width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

  height = width;

  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  percToDeg = function(perc) {
    return perc * 360;
  };

  percToRad = function(perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
  };

  degToRad = function(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${(width + margin.left) / 2}, ${(height + margin.top) / 2})`);

// build gauge bg
  for (sectionIndx = i = 1, ref = numSections; (1 <= ref ? i <= ref : i >= ref); sectionIndx = 1 <= ref ? ++i : --i) {
    arcStartRad = percToRad(totalPercent);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(sectionPerc);
    totalPercent += sectionPerc;
    startPadRad = sectionIndx === 0 ? 0 : padRad / 2;
    endPadRad = sectionIndx === numSections ? 0 : padRad / 2;
    arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth).startAngle(arcStartRad + startPadRad).endAngle(arcEndRad - endPadRad);
    chart.append('path').attr('class', `arc chart-color${sectionIndx}`).attr('d', arc);
  }

  Needle = class Needle {
    constructor(len, radius1) {
      this.len = len;
      this.radius = radius1;
    }

    drawOn(el, perc) {
      el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);
      return el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('d', this.mkCmd(perc));
    }

    animateOn(el, perc) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      return el.transition().delay(500).ease('elastic').duration(3000).selectAll('.needle').tween('progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress;
          progress = percentOfPercent * perc;
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', self.mkCmd(progress));
        };
      });
    }

    mkCmd(perc) {
      var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
      thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2); // half circle
      centerX = 0;
      centerY = 0;
      topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
      topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
      leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      return `M ${leftX} ${leftY} L ${topX} ${topY} L ${rightX} ${rightY}`;
    }

  };

  needle = new Needle(90, 15);

  needle.drawOn(chart, 0);

  needle.animateOn(chart, percent);
});


    $(function dohouse() {

    var paper = Raphael("frivardihouse", 250, 260);
    paper.customAttributes.step = function (s) {
      var len = this.orbit.getTotalLength();
      var point = this.orbit.getPointAtLength(s * len);
      return {
        transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
      };
    };


var bghouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z").attr({fill: "#cccccc", stroke: "none"});

bghouse.glow({    
    width:10,
    fill:true,
    offsetx :0,
    offsety:3,
    color:'#bfbfbf'
}
);

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')
}

function round(value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

let ltv = (100 - 80)/100;

/*let vardi = <?=$graph->CurrentPropValue?>;
let boligvardi = "Boligværdi " + formatNumber(vardi);
let boligvardilink = boligvardi.link("https://realkreditkonsulenten.dk/kundeportal/?page=property");*/

let equity = 20;
let h = 144*ltv;
let y = 86+((1-ltv)*144);
let EqText = formatNumber (equity);
let ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);

var green = "#59ba41";
var darkgreen = "#1a7266";
var yellow = "#fbb732";
var red = "#c80000";

var finalfillcolor = green;
if (ltv > 0.6) {
    finalfillcolor = darkgreen;
}
if (ltv > 0.82) {
    finalfillcolor = yellow;
}
if (ltv > 0.95) {
    finalfillcolor = red;
}

if (ltv > 1) {
    h = 144;
    y= 88;
}

var fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5,230,172.3,0).attr({fill: green, stroke: "none"});

/*skal hides hvis function mus kører*/
var sAnimation = Raphael.animation({ 'width': 172.3, 'height': h, 'x': 40.5, 'y': y, fill: finalfillcolor}, 2000, "backOut")
fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);



var thehouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z").attr({fill: "#ffffff", stroke: "none"});

var txtbelaning = paper.text(126.8,198, "BELÅNING").attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"700", "font-size": 20, "transform": "matrix(1 0 0 1 79.455 216.7752)", "fill":"#ffffff"});

/*var housevalue = paper.text(126.8,210, boligvardi).attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"400", "font-size": 13, "fill":"#ffffff"});*/



paper.customAttributes.txtprc = function (txtprc) {
  return {
    txtprc: [txtprc],
    text: Math.floor(txtprc) +"%" + '\n'
  }
}

var txtprc = paper
    .text(126.1,158.2)
    .attr({
        "font-size": 48, 
      "fill": "#ffffff",
      "font-family":"Open sans", 
      "font-weight":"700",
      txtprc: [0,1000]
    })


txtprc.animate({
   txtprc: [ltvtxt, 1000]
}, 2000, "easeInOut")


var txtfrivardi = paper.text(126.8,42.1, "FRIVÆRDI").attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"600", "font-size": 12, "transform": "matrix(1 0 0 1 98.6264 51.0823)", "fill":"#585857"});

paper.customAttributes.txtfrivardival = function (txtfrivardival) {
  return {
    txtfrivardival: [txtfrivardival],
    text: formatNumber(Math.floor(txtfrivardival)) + '\n'
  }
}

var txtfrivardival = paper
    .text(126.2,61.3)
    .attr({
        "font-size": 20, 
      "fill": "#585857",
      "font-family":"Open sans", 
      "font-weight":"700",
      txtfrivardival: [0,1000]
    })

txtfrivardival.animate({
   txtfrivardival: [equity, 1000]
}, 2000, "easeInOut")


});


};



$("#segaugeknap").click(function() {
    if($(this).text()=== "OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER"){
            $(this).text("TILBAGE");
            document.getElementById('chart-gauge').innerHTML = '';
            onload();

        }
        else{
            $(this).text("OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER");           
        }
  $('#frivardihouse, #housevalue_f, #gaugebox').slideToggle('slow');
  document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
  onload();

  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: <tspan> attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN". | Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0". | Raphael.js | wheelnav.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726921/error-tspan-attribute-dy-expected-length-nan-error-path-attribute-d)

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of the multiple houses and visible multiple gauges

```
$("#segaugeknap").click(function() {
  if($(this).text()=== "OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER"){
      $(this).text("TILBAGE");
      document.getElementById('chart-gauge').innerHTML = '';
      onload();
  } else{
      $(this).text("OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER");
      document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
      onload();
  }
  $('#frivardihouse, #housevalue_f, #gaugebox').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

You still have multiple gauges when house is shown.

`tspan` errors only happen when animation is still going. With above modification it only happens when gauge is still animating.

Comment: I tried doing this. The problem still appearing in the fiddle - and on my original page the gauge isn't showing.

I guess it's because the onload(); calls both the house and the gauge - is there maybe a way to call the functions seperately with innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't start drawing the 2 svg each time you click the bottun
So first step is to seperate the 2 drawing function and remove the onload wrapper function.

Then when you click on the guage button is to wait until the slide animation complete so we can calculate the width and height for the guage container Div after that is to draw the gauge and same for the house.

Please check the following jsfiddle i've forked yours and do the changes hope it's clear for you.

```
Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tb1k5sgc/
```

```js
pv = 80;  
pointerv = Math.round(pv);

function dogauge() {
  var Needle, arc, arcEndRad, arcStartRad, barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, el, endPadRad, height, i, margin, needle, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, percent, radius, ref, sectionIndx, sectionPerc, startPadRad, svg, totalPercent, width;

  percent = pointerv/100;

  barWidth = 40;

  numSections = 3;

  // / 2 for HALF circle
  sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;

  padRad = 0.05;

  chartInset = 10;

  // start at 270deg
  totalPercent = .75;

  el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  };

  width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = width;

  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  percToDeg = function(perc) {
    return perc * 360;
  };

  percToRad = function(perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
  };

  degToRad = function(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${(width + margin.left) / 2}, ${(height + margin.top) / 2})`);

// build gauge bg
  for (sectionIndx = i = 1, ref = numSections; (1 <= ref ? i <= ref : i >= ref); sectionIndx = 1 <= ref ? ++i : --i) {
    arcStartRad = percToRad(totalPercent);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(sectionPerc);
    totalPercent += sectionPerc;
    startPadRad = sectionIndx === 0 ? 0 : padRad / 2;
    endPadRad = sectionIndx === numSections ? 0 : padRad / 2;
    arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth).startAngle(arcStartRad + startPadRad).endAngle(arcEndRad - endPadRad);
    chart.append('path').attr('class', `arc chart-color${sectionIndx}`).attr('d', arc);
  }

  Needle = class Needle {
    constructor(len, radius1) {
      this.len = len;
      this.radius = radius1;
    }

    drawOn(el, perc) {
      el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);
      return el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('d', this.mkCmd(perc));
    }

    animateOn(el, perc) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      return el.transition().delay(500).ease('elastic').duration(3000).selectAll('.needle').tween('progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress;
          progress = percentOfPercent * perc;
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', self.mkCmd(progress));
        };
      });
    }

    mkCmd(perc) {
      var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
      thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2); // half circle
      centerX = 0;
      centerY = 0;
      topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
      topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
      leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      return `M ${leftX} ${leftY} L ${topX} ${topY} L ${rightX} ${rightY}`;
    }

  };

  needle = new Needle(90, 15);

  needle.drawOn(chart, 0);

  needle.animateOn(chart, percent);
};

function dohouse() {

    var paper = Raphael("frivardihouse", 250, 260);
    paper.customAttributes.step = function (s) {
      var len = this.orbit.getTotalLength();
      var point = this.orbit.getPointAtLength(s * len);
      return {
        transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
      };
    };

   
var bghouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z").attr({fill: "#cccccc", stroke: "none"});

bghouse.glow({    
    width:10,
    fill:true,
    offsetx :0,
    offsety:3,
    color:'#bfbfbf'
}
);

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')
}

function round(value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

let ltv = (100 - 80)/100;

/*let vardi = <?=$graph->CurrentPropValue?>;
let boligvardi = "Boligværdi " + formatNumber(vardi);
let boligvardilink = boligvardi.link("https://realkreditkonsulenten.dk/kundeportal/?page=property");*/

let equity = 20;
let h = 144*ltv;
let y = 86+((1-ltv)*144);
let EqText = formatNumber (equity);
let ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);

var green = "#59ba41";
var darkgreen = "#1a7266";
var yellow = "#fbb732";
var red = "#c80000";

var finalfillcolor = green;
if (ltv > 0.6) {
 finalfillcolor = darkgreen;
}
if (ltv > 0.82) {
 finalfillcolor = yellow;
}
if (ltv > 0.95) {
 finalfillcolor = red;
}

if (ltv > 1) {
 h = 144;
 y= 88;
}

var fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5,230,172.3,0).attr({fill: green, stroke: "none"});

/*skal hides hvis function mus kører*/
var sAnimation = Raphael.animation({ 'width': 172.3, 'height': h, 'x': 40.5, 'y': y, fill: finalfillcolor}, 2000, "backOut")
fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);



var thehouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z").attr({fill: "#ffffff", stroke: "none"});

var txtbelaning = paper.text(126.8,198, "BELÅNING").attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"700", "font-size": 20, "transform": "matrix(1 0 0 1 79.455 216.7752)", "fill":"#ffffff"});

/*var housevalue = paper.text(126.8,210, boligvardi).attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"400", "font-size": 13, "fill":"#ffffff"});*/



paper.customAttributes.txtprc = function (txtprc) {
  return {
    txtprc: [txtprc],
    text: Math.floor(txtprc) +"%" + '\n'
  }
}

var txtprc = paper
    .text(126.1,158.2)
    .attr({
     "font-size": 48, 
      "fill": "#ffffff",
      "font-family":"Open sans", 
      "font-weight":"700",
      txtprc: [0,1000]
    })


txtprc.animate({
   txtprc: [ltvtxt, 1000]
}, 2000, "easeInOut")


var txtfrivardi = paper.text(126.8,42.1, "FRIVÆRDI").attr({"font-family": "Open sans", "font-weight":"600", "font-size": 12, "transform": "matrix(1 0 0 1 98.6264 51.0823)", "fill":"#585857"});

paper.customAttributes.txtfrivardival = function (txtfrivardival) {
  return {
    txtfrivardival: [txtfrivardival],
    text: formatNumber(Math.floor(txtfrivardival)) + '\n'
  }
}

var txtfrivardival = paper
    .text(126.2,61.3)
    .attr({
     "font-size": 20, 
      "fill": "#585857",
      "font-family":"Open sans", 
      "font-weight":"700",
      txtfrivardival: [0,1000]
    })

txtfrivardival.animate({
   txtfrivardival: [equity, 1000]
}, 2000, "easeInOut")


};

$("#segaugeknap").click(function() {
 $('#frivardihouse, #gaugebox').slideToggle(400);
 if($(this).text()=== "OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER"){
            $(this).text("TILBAGE");
            document.getElementById('chart-gauge').innerHTML = '';
      setTimeout(dogauge, 401);   
        }
        else{
            $(this).text("OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER");      
             
  document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
  setTimeout(dohouse, 401);
        }
 
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
dohouse();
})
```

```css
.chart-gauge {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.chart-color1 {
  fill: rgb(200,0,0);
}

.chart-color2 {
  fill: rgb(251, 183, 50);
}

.chart-color3 {
  fill: rgb(89, 186, 65);;
}

.needle,
.needle-center {
  fill: #464A4F;
}

.prose {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ababab;
}
.gaugebox {display: none; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px !important;margin-top: -10px !important;padding: 0px 10px 20px 10px !important;}

#segauge {background-color:#000;color:#fff;width:300px;margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;padding:10px;}

.gaugebox h4 {text-align: center;font-weight: 700;margin-bottom: 0px;}

.gaugebox .gaugetxt span:first-child(){float: left;}
.gaugebox .gaugetxt span:nth-child(2){float: right;}
.gaugetxt {width: 360px; margin: 0 auto;}


.gaugefullwrapper {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.gaugewrapper {margin: 0 auto; width: 350px }
div#gauge {
    width: 80%;height: 180px;margin: 0 auto;
}

/*hus*/
div#frivardihouse svg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(.87,-.41,.19,1.44)
}

div#frivardihouse svg:hover {transform: scale(1.04);
}

div#frivardihouse {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.housevalue_f {text-align: center;padding-bottom: 10px;}
.housevalue_f a span {color: #17aec6;}
.housevalue_f a {color: #666666;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>

<div class="housegauge">
 
  
  <div class="graphs house">
  <div id="frivardihouse"></div>
    
<div class="w-btn-wrapper align_center" id="segauge"><span id="segaugeknap" class="w-btn style_solid size_medium color_primary icon_none">OVERVÅGNINGSBAROMETER</span></div>
 </div>





<div class="gaugebox" id="gaugebox">
 <div class="gaugefullwrapper">
  <div class="gaugewrapper">
   <div id="chart-gauge" class="chart-gauge"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gaugetxt">
   <span>Langt fra omlægning</span><span>Tæt på omlægning</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```